# is possible to embed in a string a variable that can be set later with 'format' method?

Tags: python, string

Recently I have seen a code with a method of a class that suggests me this but I've not seen anything like this in the documentation.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.total_steps = 0

    def my_func(self, step, logs={}):
        self.total_steps += 1
        filepath = self.filepath.format(step=self.total_steps, **logs)
        self.another_func(filepath)
    [...]
```

I think that this code permits me to use a `filepath` variable with some inner-parameter `step` that could be updated through `format` whenever I want. However, I'm not able to pass `filepath` such that it is influenced by `format(step=self.total_steps, **logs)`.

So my question is: is it possible to define a string with a parameter that could be changed with `format` method?

---

If you want to know the original code I could post here or could you give a check by yourself at `keras-rl` library on github. It's in the `ModelIntervalCheckpoint` class in the [`callbacks.py`](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/master/rl/callbacks.py) file.

Comment: The `filepath` string would have to contain `'{step}'`, which would be replaced by what's provided as keyword argument in `.format(step=...)`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about answering this... it should be obvious how to do that if you have any idea what the `format` method does.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yeah, you're right. And now I know another feature of format. I don't know why I missed it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to be able to format your filepath, you need to include a "placeholder" named "step" in your filepath string.

```
a = MyClass("/foo/bar/{step}/bla")
```

A great overview of the format features: https://pyformat.info/